# Ignore NaN elements in a matrix - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Hi I need to ignore `NaN` elements in my matrix, please see the code below:

```
Coord = [230 400; 270 420; 300 400;340 430;390 380; 230 300; 
         300 290;370 280;250 200;290 200 ;320 200 ;200 190 
         ;250 100 ;310 120; 410 110; 390 180;];

P =  [1 6 7 3 2 1 NaN NaN;
      3 7 8 5 4 3 NaN NaN;
      6 9 10 7 6 NaN NaN NaN;
      7 10 11 8 7 NaN NaN NaN;
      6 12 13 14 10 9 6 NaN;
      8 11 10 14 15 16 8 NaN];
```

you can see that the total number of rows in `Coord` and the maximum value of the matrix `P` is equal to `16`

When i try to do this: `Coord(P(1,:),:)`
what i expect to get:

```
230   400
230   300
300   290
300   400
270   420
230   400
```

Instead i get following **error**:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Comment: Nothing makes really sense here. The matrices `Coord` and `P` don't have the same dimensions, not even the same number of elements.And what is `Polygon`?  Be **much** clearer, what your input and what your desired output is.

Comment: Don't use arrays to represent your polygons! Use cell arrays. Then there's no need to fill the rows with `NaN`s. `P = {[1,6,7,3,2,1], [3,7,8,5,4,3], ...}` . Then you can get the polygons via `P{1}`, `P{2}`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input:**

```
P =  [1 6 7 3 2 1 NaN NaN;
      3 7 8 5 4 3 NaN NaN;
      6 9 10 7 6 NaN NaN NaN;
      7 10 11 8 7 NaN NaN NaN;
      6 12 13 14 10 9 6 NaN;
      8 11 10 14 15 16 8 NaN];

Coord = [230 400; 270 420; 300 400;340 430;390 380; 230 300;...
         300 290;370 280;250 200;290 200 ;320 200 ;200 190;...
         250 100 ;310 120; 410 110; 390 180;];
```

**Code:**

```
for i = 1:length(P(:,1))
    Q = P(i,isfinite(P(i, :)));
    disp(Coord(Q,:));
end
```

**Output:**

```
230   400
230   300
300   290
300   400
270   420
230   400

300   400
300   290
370   280
390   380
340   430
300   400

230   300
250   200
290   200
300   290
230   300

300   290
290   200
320   200
370   280
300   290

230   300
200   190
250   100
310   120
290   200
250   200
230   300

370   280
320   200
290   200
310   120
410   110
390   180
370   280
```

Answer (score 1):

```
c = Coords(~isnan(P) | (P > 0))
p = P(~isnan(P) | (P > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

A good start would be the function `isnan(someVector)`.  That will return a logical the same length as `someVector` true in the indices where `someVector` contains a `NaN` value.  As an example,

```
>> isnan(P(1,:))
    ans = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
>> notNaN = ~isnan(P(1,:));
>> P(1,notNaN)
    ans = [1 6 7 3 2 1]
```

That's a way to ignore `NaN` values.  For zero, we can do something similar, but instead of having a function to do it for us, we have to create the logical test.  Your matrix doesn't have values of zero, but here's how I would get around said values:

```
>> nonZero = P(1,P(1,:)~=0)
```

where `P(1,:)~=0` is creating a logical array in the same way that `isnan(P(1,:))` did

Comment: Please see my modification to the question. 

Coord(~isnan(Polygon(1,:)),:)

Comment: 230   400
   270   420
   300   400
   340   430
   390   380
   230   300


Not the expected results.